# Is it possible to customize outliers calculation formula in ggplot?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

```
mydata3<-data.frame(x=(c(1:10,20,100,120)))

mydata3%>%ggplot(aes(x=x))+
  geom_boxplot(
  )
```

[image]

What is the formula of outliers calculation in ggplot ? `Quartile1- 1.5*IQR and Quartile3 +1.5*IQR` ?
If so, can I mannualy change this rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your calculation for outliers is correct. From the docs:

> The lower and upper hinges correspond to the first and third quartiles (the 25th and 75th percentiles).

and

> The upper whisker extends from the hinge to the largest value no further than 1.5 * IQR from the hinge (where IQR is the inter-quartile range, or distance between the first and third quartiles). The lower whisker extends from the hinge to the smallest value at most 1.5 * IQR of the hinge.

To change the positions of the whiskers and hinges, we can use `stat = "summary"` inside `geom_boxplot`, and pass our own summary function. This needs to be a function that takes the passed values and returns a data frame with columns `ymin`, `lower`, `middle`, `upper` and `ymax`.

In this example, we set the whisker tips at 10th and 90th centile, the hinges at 40th and 60th centile, and the middle line at the 50th centile:

```r
mydata3 <- data.frame(x=(c(1:10,20,100,120)))

mydata3 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = 0, x = x)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "summary",
               fun.data = ~ data.frame(ymin   = quantile(.x, 0.1),
                                       lower  = quantile(.x, 0.4),
                                       middle = quantile(.x, 0.5),
                                       upper  = quantile(.x, 0.6),
                                       ymax   = quantile(.x, 0.9)),
               orientation = "y")
```

[image]

Note that if we change the quantiles in the above function, we get a different boxplot:

```r
mydata3 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = 0, x = x)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "summary",
               fun.data = ~ data.frame(ymin   = quantile(.x, 0.05),
                                       lower  = quantile(.x, 0.1),
                                       middle = quantile(.x, 0.5),
                                       upper  = quantile(.x, 0.9),
                                       ymax   = quantile(.x, 0.95)),
               orientation = "y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Does something like this work?

```
mydata3<-data.frame(x=(c(1:10,20,100,120)))

mydata3%>%ggplot(aes(x=x))+ stat_boxplot(coef = 5) +
  geom_boxplot()
```